# Is there a way to get a trigger_id with an emoji reaction with the Slack API?

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I'm attempting to trigger a Modal View using Bolt by listening for the `reaction_added` event.

Something like

```py
@app.event("reaction_added")
def react(event):
    # return a modal view based on emoji reaction added
```

but the response on a `reaction_added` [event](https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added) doesn't seem to come with a `trigger_id` which is required for the Modal.

Is there a workaround for getting a `trigger_id` to get a Modal view to be returned on an emoji reaction?

Comment: Curious, what is the use case for triggering a modal on adding a reaction? Also, are you basing your conclusion that the trigger_id is missing based on the sample object in the linked documentation or did you see what the structure of the event object looks like when the reaction_added event is triggered?


Just in case you aren't able to receive an answer here I highly recommend contacting slack support, their platform experts are very knowledgeable and quick to respond

Comment: @SanchitBatra thanks for the information. :]. I'm trying to collect data on support conversations within Slack to understand support loads. As for the missing trigger_id, I saw the JSON response and from that I made my assumption

Comment: I would try and put a breakpoint right after the function gets invoked and see the structure of event, you might be getting a trigger_id there and the documentation just shows part of the attributes.

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? I have the same problem :/

Comment: Hey @DaniloToro I didn't unfortunately :/ hopefully you can be the one to post an answer here :)

Comment: Thanks @elyakshaver, I talked to the support team and they tell me that I can send a message to the channel with a button, after that, trigger a modal clicking this button. There is no other way for now